# How many mysqld nodes in comparison with data nodes in a mysql cluster?

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I have a cluster with 3 ndbd nodes.

How many MySQLd nodes do I need. What is a good rule.
One MySQLd for 3 ndbd?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on too many factors too give a short answer.

But I would put a mysqld node in each application server so application always access mysqld through localhost. It will be as easy to scale as your application is.